# Dynamic doc blocks for type hinting and autocomplete with dynamic output classes

Tags: php, pdo, ide, phpdoc

I have a medium-sized MVC application.  The use cases for the app are such that I require a bit more control of the SQL used to interact with my database (among other things, data is highly normalized and we use a LOT of joins).  So, I've grown my own design for models, rather than using Doctrine or Eloquent or anything.  I recently discovered my design is called the [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) pattern.  At any rate, it looks like this (simplified a bit for clarity):

We have an an abstract class which all my TableGateways extend.  It knows how to talk to PDO and do SQL stuff, but not about any particular table:

```
abstract class TableGateway {

    protected $db = null;

    public $tableName = '';

    public $outputClass = null;

    function __contruct(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

    /**
     * $return \StdClass[]
     */
    function all() {
        $result = $this->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s',$this->tableName));
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @param array $params
     * @return \StdClass[]
     */
    public function query($query, $params = array()) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        if($this->outputClass) {
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $this->outputClass);
        } else {
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        $success = $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Then each table has a gateway class which extends the parent class and applies the table-specific stuff.  There will be a lot of functions in here which call `$this->query()`, bringing their knowledge of the table's structure to build a useful query, but there are also some basic functions, like `PostsGateway::all()` which are the same for every table, so they live in the parent class.

```
class PostsGateway extends TableGateway {
    public $tableName = 'posts';

    public $outputClass = 'Post';
}
```

Each result from the query is loaded into an object.  By default they are just StdClass objects, but you can specify an alternate `$this->outputClass` to have them output in that other class, like this one:

```
class Post {
    /** @var int $id */
    /** @var string $content */
}
```

All this is working pretty well for me.  However, my IDE can't keep up.  You and I know that `PostsGateway::all()` is going to return an array `Post` objects, but the IDE thinks it's just a regular array.  This means I don't autocomplete hints for the properties of the `Post` objects.

Does anyone know any clever ways to resolve this, so the IDE will know about the change?

I was thinking about a script to automatically generate doc blocks for `PostsGateway`, but I'm a little leary of code gen in general, and especially code gen in a class I'm going to modify periodically.  The script would have to periodically update the doc blocks, based on changes to `TableGateway`, and not mess up anything I've added to `PostsGateway`.

Are there any other cool ways to do get around this?  Or can you recommend some good libraries for generating this code blocks?